# embedding cursor file

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I use VS 2008 and C#, I want to embed cursor file (x.cur) in the resources, to be included in the EXE and I want to call it.

Any suggestion to do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Add the file to your application resources`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy(v=vs.80).aspx) and use something like this to load it:

```
var cursor = new Cursor(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("x.cur"));
```

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. , I added it as image , but it raise the below error

Comment: Try loading it to a `MemoryStream` object and then cast it to a `Cursor` object.